# DC motor efficiency

Tags: motor, dc, dc-motor, efficiency, torque

I would like to build a Moment of Inertia machine:
A machine that rotates an object (with a DC motor) and can also record the angular velocity and use this to find the moment of inertia.

Initially I used an energy approach, relating P in (VI) and P out (KE/time)x efficiency and rearrange to get the moment of inertia in terms of rotation time, voltage and current. The issue is that efficiency is not constant. I may need to substitute an expression for the efficiency, or have a completely new approach involving torque. Also in the first way the torque isn’t in the equation which is unsettling for the fixed torque motor.

I have not started building the project, so although I would really like to build it, if it’s too complicated for a yr12 project I may choose something else.

How can I calculate the efficiency of a DC motor, depending on perhaps the speed, torque, voltage etc?
Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
You haven't actually asked aquestion. Show us what you have already done. Please nderstand that this is a question and answer site, not a forum.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to know how you can calculate the efficiency of a DC motor, depending on perhaps the speed, torque, voltage etc.

Comment: Karim, Edit your question and add the question in your comment to it.

Comment: Why not just drive your DC motor with a constant current, which -- for a high-enough quality motor -- should give you a constant torque out?

Comment: while this could be useful if I decide to take a torque-based approach, the idea is that I can relate the power input of the motor to the power output of the motor, thus being able to find the kinetic energy. I would prefer to take the energy approach rather than the forces approach as this should (hopefully) keep the problem not too complicated. Although I may use the torque approach if there is no other way.

Comment: just measure P while spinning up an unloaded motor. Then you can subtract that amount from the amount taken with an object attached. You can also weigh the motor, estimate it's materials, and calculate an average specific heat for it, which would let you ballpark efficiency by measuring resulting temperatures.

Comment: this was extremely useful. Thank you Dan

Comment: hey Boss, Just wanted to check if you can really neglect the minor power losses, other than the heat loss. I'm not too fussed about having an inaccuracy but I was wondering how significant this approximation would be (for the second method). Thanks

Comment: One point to consider is type of motor: EC/BLDC or "brushed"? PM, shunt/series/compound wound? Looking for inertia, computing the efficiency is not as direct as *energy put into rotation*. Outside EE, there are various ways to apply a known torque or measure torque. I'd take the easy route and measure objects of known inertia for reference.

Comment: I was thinking of a brushed motor, but if a different motor is advantageous I will use that one instead. A problem with torque is that at a constant speed the total torque will be 0. I could measure angular acceleration and use that but the angular acceleration acts very briefly and therefore seems hard to measure. I might be missing something though

Comment: Ok i think i got it. Using P=torque x angular velocity, and substituting in KE/t for power i can find MoI in terms of torque, time and angle traveled. This seems quite a bit easier and i hope I have not oversimplified it, can someone please verify this? Also sorry I realised this has become a bit much physics rather than electrical engineering.

Answer (score 1):

### **Method for calculating DC-Motor efficiency:**

First of all we need to understand that a DC-Motors efficency is depending on the load torque applied to the motor.
In below example of a motor performance curve you can see that each load-torque will have its very own efficiency.

[image: example performance curve of 12V brushed dc-motor]

**To calculate the efficiency for each load point you can use following formula:**

[image]

(it is important to use SI-Units as indicated in [ ] brackets, otherwise you have to adjust factor pi/30 accordingly)

Comment: That efficiency curve causes so many problems. That is a curve for a motor that does not utilize speed or torque control, but instead uses a fixed input voltage. If the motor is being controlled electronically, then that graph is not very helpful, because the voltage will be changed continuously on the fly during operation.

Answer (score 1):

The output power of the motor is speed * torque where speed is in rad/sec and torque is in Nm.

The input power of the DC motor is V * I where 'V' is input voltage and 'I' is input current.

The main power loss in the motor is due to the resistance in the current path. That power loss is P = I^2 * R where P is the power loss, I is the input current and R is the resistance in the conductive path.

The output torque of the motor is Kt * I where Kt is the torque constant of the motor, and I is the input current.

So you can estimate the output power of the motor if you know Kt, I, and speed. And you can estimate the power loss in the motor if you know I and R. Be advised that R is not constant with temperature. As the motor winding heats up, R will increase by about 4 percent every 10 degrees C.